# What could make a program behaves differently inside `strace`?

Tags: linux, debian, strace

This is related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/485682/40697 but I decided to take a more developer-oriented approach.

For some reason, I cannot install packages on my system when logged in over the Bluetooth serial console:

```
# dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-server_1%3a7.4p1-10+deb9u4_armhf.deb 
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 wait for subprocess dpkg-split failed: No child processes
```

I tried to trace back the issue using `strace`. However:

```
# strace -e trace=fork dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-server_1%3a7.4p1-10+deb9u4_armhf.deb
[...]
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=7046, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=1} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

As you can see, when running inside `strace` the process completed with exit status 0 (and the package was installed). But when working outside of `strace`, `dpkg` systematically fails.

FWIW, when running inside `gdb` the process fails too:

```
# gdb /usr/bin/dpkg
(gdb) run -i /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-server_1%3a7.4p1-10+deb9u4_armhf.deb 
Starting program: /usr/bin/dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-server_1%3a7.4p1-10+deb9u4_armhf.deb
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 wait for subprocess dpkg-split failed: No child processes
```

Now my question: what could explain the `dpkg` program to behave differently when running inside `strace`?

Comment: Have you, maybe per accident, given strace root or other special system user permissions so that traced progs can run with higher privileges?

Comment: @Klaus I don't think so. I can't see anything that could suggest `strace` runs with elevated privileges.

Comment: Timing, for one

Comment: Yes @n.m. Possible.

Comment: Interesting one; wouldn't one also expect timing differences when executed under `gdb`?

Comment: @tink It is not that obvious since apparently the issue is caused by a child process forked from `dpkg`. I will try to step into the child process (if gdb can do that?)

Comment: `strace` can follow child processes with `-f`

Comment: @hek2mgl With `strace -f` I can trace the (possibly) faulty system call. But in `strace` it does not fail. In `gdb`, using `set follow-fork-mode` I can trace until the same call, but when I step at this point I get a 1 second pause then the message `process 24043 is executing new program: /usr/bin/dpkg-split
[Inferior 2 (process 24043) exited with code 01]
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 wait for subprocess dpkg-split failed: No child processes
`

Comment: Interesting. Please keep us up to date here! :)

Comment: I'm more and more convinced there is a race condition involved somewhere. I will keep you informed if I find anything.

Comment: Some possible other reasons:
[colored output slower](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36964/ls-behaves-differently-under-strace),
[timing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598305/what-could-make-a-program-behaves-differently-inside-strace)
([another](https://superuser.com/questions/1641282/why-does-strace-change-command-behavior)),
[setuid/setgid bit](https://superuser.com/questions/247888/strange-strace-and-setuid-behaviour-permission-denied-under-strace-but-not-run),
([another](https://superuser.com/questions/1059198/why-strace-sudo-command-bombs-when-sudo-command-works))

Answer (score 0):

I remember that this has been discussed on the internet before :)

https://github.com/strace/strace/issues/14

Basically you can create a wrapper script, like this (as root):

```
dpkg_path="$(which dpkg)"
mv -v "${dpkg_path}" /usr/bin/dpkg-orig

> "{dpkg_path}" cat << 'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
# pro-tip: You could use a slow disk or an old usb stick
# if writes to /dev/null turn out to be too fast
exec strace -e trace=none -e signal=none -qq -o /dev/null /usr/bin/dpkg-orig "${@}"
EOF

chmod +x "${dpkg_path}"
```

`dpkg` should work on your system now.

Comment: LoL. I already wrote a function for that ;)
But that doesn't solve the question of knowing why/how it does work differently when running from `strace`.

Comment: I wasn't super serious when writing this, but I think it belongs here! :) I like those _works with strace_ bug reports! I remember one guy on the internet calling it _medicinal use of strace_. My best guess would also be timing. Certain things take a little bit longer when the process runs with strace. That can make a difference especially when it comes to race conditions.

Comment: PS: ... well, I'm surprised that the error happens when you run it with gdb.

Comment: Added a link to the discussion about _medicinal use of strace_ :)